# getting data out of XML <![CDATA[]]> with php

Tags: php, xml

I have to following XML file and i would like to get only the image url.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<Events>
  -<title>
    -<![CDATA[
      Parktheater Eindhoven | Voorstellingen
    ]]>
  </title>
  <pubDate>Fri, 22 Apr 2016 11:20:31 +0200</pubDate>
  -<show id="4822">
    -<kvksysteem_code>
      -<![CDATA[
        4822
      ]]>
    </kvksysteem_code>
    -<title>
      -<![CDATA[
      ]]>
    </title>
    -<performer>
      -<name>
        -<![CDATA[
          Ik blijf/word vriend van Parktheater Eindhoven
        ]]>
      </name>
    </performer>
    -<shortDescription>
      -<![CDATA
        [&nbsp;
        &nbsp;
        Meer informatie over de de Vrienden van Parktheater Eindhoven, klik hier&gt;&gt;
      ]]>
    </shortDescription>
    -<performance>
      <startDate>2016-07-01</startDate>
      <startTime>22:22:00</startTime>
      -<pauseTime>
        -<![CDATA[
        ]]>
      </pauseTime>
      <endDate/>
      <endTime/>
    </performance>
    -<detailUrl>
      -<![CDATA[
        http://www.parktheater.nl/programma/2029/Ik_blijf_word_vriend_van_Parktheater_Eindhoven//
      ]]>
    </detailUrl>
    -<images>
      -<URL>
        -<![CDATA[
          http://www.parktheater.nl/cms_files/system/images/img2416_08.jpg
        ]]>
      </URL>
    </images>
  </show>
  +<show id="4862">
  +<show id="3939">
  +<show id="3939">
  +<show id="4202">
  +<show id="4202">
  +<show id="4201">
  +<show id="4201">
  +<show id="3941">
  +<show id="3940">
  +<show id="3940">
  .....
```

I also have to following script where data is being fetched from an API. The show ID in the XML is the same as the $ticketmaticid in query.php. i would like to echo the correct image from the XML with the correct show.

```
$nextevents = file_get_contents('<API URL');
$json_t = json_decode($nextevents,true);
echo "<table>";
if(count($json_t["data"])>0){
  for ($i=0; $i<count(json_t["data"]); $i++)
  {
    $uitvoerende[$i]=str_replace("'", "&#039;", $json_t["data"][$i]["name"]);
    $titel[$i]=str_replace('/[â-zA-Z0-9\_\-]/', $json_t["data"][$i]["group"]["name"]);
    $zaalid[$i]=str_replace('/[â-zA-Z0-9\_\-]/', $json_t["data"][$i]["locations"]["0"]["id"]);
    $starttijd[$i]=str_replace("'", "&#039;", $json_t["data"][$i]["defaultschedulestarttime"]);
    $datum[$i]=str_replace("'", "&#039;", $json_t["data"][$i]["startdate"]);
    $ticketmaticid[$i]=str_replace('/[â-zA-Z0-9\_\-]/', $json_t["data"][$i]["attributes"]["ticketmaticid"]);

    echo "<tr><td>HERE DO I WANT TE IMAGE"</td><td>Titel: ".$titel[$i]."<br> Gezelschap: ".$uitvoerende[$i]."<br><a href='https://www.parktheater.nl/programma/code/".$ticketmaticid[$i]."'>Klik hier<a></td><td>Zaal: ".$zaal[$i]."<br>Datum: ".$datum[$i]."<br>Start: ".$starttijd[$i]."<br></td></tr>";
  }
}
echo "</table>";
```

I have consulted with my supervisor, because its my iternship. And he pointed to me that if i fetch the XML feed the page should load to slow. So i think it needs to be done on an different way. The XML also contains show in the past but the page doesnt allow this. So it will be wishful that it only collects data from the feed where the ID matches $ticketmaticid in the API. and then gets te URL and echos it

Comment: The API URL is providing JSON then? Cause you shouldn't be using json_decode on XML. Use `simplexml_load_string()`.

Comment: Yes! the api url is providing JSON. The XML file is an RSS feed on a different URL. Because the API does not have te image which belongs to the shows. those links are in XML file. however <show id=""> is the same as $ticketmaticid in the API.

So basicly i want to get <images><URL> form the XML and connect it to $ticketmaticid in de echo so the array would be compete with an picture and the information which is already there from the API